# Is there a system of quasigroup equations implying non-associativity?

Tags: co.combinatorics, non-associative-algebras

I have read that if 4 quasigroup operations, $\cdot,\circ,\star,\square$, on a set $S$ respect the following equation:
$$x\cdot (y\circ z) = (x \star y) \square z$$ 
for all $x,y,z\in S$, then all 4 quasigroups are isotopic to the same group.

I was wondering if a similar (or in some ways oposite) result could be hoped for:

> Could there exist a system of quasigroup equations implying non-associativity?

That is, could there exist a solvable system of quasigroup equations such that in every solution at least one of the quasigroups is isotopic to a non-associative loop (i.e., $\textbf{not}$ isotopic to a group)?

Note: In the system of equations, a quasigroup operation should not appear more than once in any single equation.

**Edit:** The following types of equations are allowed

1. An equation specifying two quasigroup operations are not isotopic such as $\cdot\not\equiv \circ$ (meaning for every 3 bijections $\varphi,\psi,\theta:S\to S$, there exist $x,y\in S$ such that $\theta(\varphi(x)\cdot \psi(y))\neq x\circ y$).
2. A regular quasigroup equation - such equations must contain at least 3 quasigroup operations.
3. An inexsitence equation of the following form: There does not exist a quasigroup operation $\square$ such that $(x\cdot y)\square (y \circ z)=x \star z$.

Also, you can assume any lower bound (but not upper bound) you wish on the size of $S$ (this can be done by using the type 1 equations above).

Comment: In any such system of equations, the one element quasigroup will satisfy all of them, and be associative.  So, no.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely answers what I asked, but unfortunately not what I wanted to ask. I've revised the question, and hopefully it now asks what was intended.

Comment: Using the word "equation" for some relation that declares two things not equal throws me off-kilter.  This related item (Associative nontrivial hyperidentities in semigroups by Movsisyan and Hakobyan) may be of interest, although it may not help with this question.  They consider universal second order statements of varying flavors which assert all operations involved are associative, including term operations.  Maybe some negation of what they do will shed light. Gerhard "Ask Me About Hyperassociative Theories" Paseman, 2014.01.13

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at that paper. I guess you are right and equation is not the right word here.